# 404 not found error while creating custom group and fields in system configuration

Tags: configuration

I am trying to create a group and some fields for my custom section under custom tab

Tab and section is getting created.But when i click on the section in the content area it shows 404 not found error

my system.xml file is as follows

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <!--node is just an identifier-->
        <animala translate="label" module="training_animal">
            <label>Training</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </animala>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <animals translate="label" module="training_animal">
            <class>seperator-top</class>
            <label>Training</label>
            <!--node vlaue should match the tabs node name-->
            <tab>animala</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

            <groups>
                <training_animal_group translate="label">
                    <label>My Custom Group</label>
                    <comment>Some comment about my group</comment>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <training_animal_field translate="label tooltip comment">
                            <label>My Custom Field</label>
                            <comment>Some comment about my field</comment>
                            <tooltip>Field ToolTip</tooltip>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        </training_animal_field>
                    </fields>
                </training_animal_group>
            </groups>
        </animals>
    </sections>
</config>
```

The url of my section is

```
http://localhost/mage2/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/animal/
```

module config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Training_Animal>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </Training_Animal>
</modules>
```

Training_Animal_Block

```
    <training_animal>
        <class>Training_Animal_Helper</class>
    </training_animal>

</helpers>
```

Comment: I would like to thank everyone involved in this thread for helping me immensely :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should also set your ACL resources for the custom system config group. I assume you are using Magento > 1.5. In your `adminhtml.xml` (`app/code/{codepool}/Training/Animal/etc/adminhtml.xml`):

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <animals translate="title" module="training_animal">
                                        <title>Animals</title>
                                        <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                                    </animals>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

In earlier version of Magento this information was stored in the `config.xml`.

Comment: Also, after you add this file, log out and log in again, to let Magento refresh ACL rules.

Comment: Actually i had set my acl resource. but i did not logout and login. Its working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks fmrng. This helped me. Earlier I was missing with some of the tags in acl resources...