# 404 Error Page not found. while creating custom group and fields in system configuration

Tags: system-configuration

I am trying to create a group and some fields for my custom section under custom tab.

Tab and section is getting created.But when I click on the section in the content area it shows 404 not found error

my **system.xml** file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <tabs>
        <dateconfig translate="label" module="date">
            <label>Irs Extensions</label>
            <sort_order>401</sort_order>
        </dateconfig>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <dateoptions translate="label" module="date">
            <label>Date Hellooworld options</label>
            <tab>dateconfig</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <message translate="label">
                    <label>Date Demo Config File</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type> 
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </message>
            </groups>
        </dateoptions>

    </sections>

</config>
```

the url of my section is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/karthi/mage1924/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/dateoptions/
```

I tried Below Post and googled lot but I could not resolve this issue.

[404 not found error while creating custom group and fields in system configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/404-not-found-error-while-creating-custom-group-and-fields-in-system-configurati)

But, When i added this below lines of coding it gets successfully
added in a  new group in the general Tab called “Example of Adding a Group”.

```
        <general>
            <groups>
                <example>
                    <label>Example of Adding a Group</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </example>
            </groups>
        </general>
```

Below my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Irs_Date>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Irs_Date>
    </modules>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <date>
                    <use>admin</use>
                 <args>
                    <module>Irs_Date</module>
                    <frontName>admindate</frontName>
                 </args>
                </date>
            </routers>
         </admin>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <date>
                <class>Irs_Date_Helper</class>
            </date>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <date>
                <class>Irs_Date_Block</class>
            </date>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <date_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </date_write>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <date translate="title" module="date">
                                        <title>date Section</title>
                                        <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                                    </date>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: what you have tried ? have you added acl in adminhtml.xml OR config.xml ?

Comment: then logout and re-login and check

Comment: i have  added acl in adminhtml.xml, but none worked, flushed magento cache and done login logout, it shows 404 error page not found

Comment: @MineshPatel, 2 what am i missing?

Comment: anybody can help me to slove this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I looked following blog, which helped me solving this issue, thanks to alanstorm for writing an awesome blog

http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Solved my 404 Error issue. Seems like it was an ACL related error. So I rewrote my acl part carefully.

Old Adminhtml.xml

```
 <config>
          <acl>
                <resources>
                    <admin>
                        <children>
                            <system>
                                <children>
                                    <config>
                                        <children>
                                            <date_options translate="title" module="date">
                                                <title>date Section</title>
                                                <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                                            </date_options>
                                        </children>
                                    </config>
                                </children>
                            </system>
                        </children>
                    </admin>
                </resources>
            </acl>
    </config>
```

updated new adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
          <acl>
                <resources>
                    <admin>
                        <children>
                            <system>
                                <children>
                                    <config>
                                        <children>
                                            <date_options translate="title" module="date">
                                                <title>date Section</title>
                                                <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                                            </date_options>
                                        </children>
                                    </config>
                                </children>
                            </system>
                        </children>
                    </admin>
                </resources>
            </acl>
    </config>
```

It should be date_options instead of date

Comment: i am new to stackexchange , i really liked about stackexchage , hereafter going to use continuously. thanks to alanstorm,

Comment: old and new adminhtml.xml are equals in your example.
Anyway this blog is an excelent source of information about magento.
This solve my problem too, thanks!