# Page not found 404 when accessing custom module in system configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, system.xml, system-config

When i try to access my system > configuration > i got an error saying page not found 404

here's my code:

config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lime_Sellercenter>
            <version>0.0.0.4</version>
        </Lime_Sellercenter>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <lime_sellercenter>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Lime_Sellercenter</module>
                    <frontName>lime_sellercenter</frontName>
                </args>
            </lime_sellercenter>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Lime_Sellercenter before="Mage_Adminhtml">Lime_Sellercenter_Adminhtml</Lime_Sellercenter>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <models>
            <lime_sellercenter>
                <class>Lime_Sellercenter_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>lime_sellercenter_resource</resourceModel>
            </lime_sellercenter>
            <lime_sellercenter_resource>
                <class>Lime_Sellercenter_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                   <listing>
                        <table>lime_sellercenter_listing</table>
                    </listing>
                    <listingattributes>
                      <table>lime_sellercenter_listing_attributes</table>
                    </listingattributes>
                    <listing_store>
                        <table>lime_sellercenter_listing_store</table>
                    </listing_store>
                    <listing_product>
                        <table>lime_sellercenter_listing_product</table>
                    </listing_product>
                    <lazadacategories>
                        <table>lime_sellercenter_lazadacategories</table>
                    </lazadacategories>
                    <ordersyncqueue>
                        <table>lime_sellercenter_ordersyncqueue</table>
                    </ordersyncqueue>
                    <ordererrorlog>
                        <table>lime_sellercenter_ordererrorlog</table>
                    </ordererrorlog>
                </entities>
            </lime_sellercenter_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <lime_sellercenter>
                <class>Lime_Sellercenter_Block</class>
            </lime_sellercenter>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <lime_sellercenter>
                <class>Lime_Sellercenter_Helper</class>
            </lime_sellercenter>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <lime_sellercenter_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Lime_Sellercenter</module>
                    <class>Lime_Sellercenter_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </lime_sellercenter_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <lime_sellercenter>
                        <class>lime_sellercenter/observer</class>
                        <method>orderCancel</method>
                    </lime_sellercenter>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <catalog_product_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <lime_sellercenter>
                        <class>lime_sellercenter/observer</class>
                        <method>afterProductSave</method>
                    </lime_sellercenter>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_commit_after> 
            <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <lime_sellercenter>
                        <class>lime_sellercenter/observer</class>
                        <method>syncOrderButton</method>
                    </lime_sellercenter>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <sales_order_shipment_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <lime_sellercenter>
                        <class>lime_sellercenter/observer</class>
                        <method>afterShipmentSave</method>
                    </lime_sellercenter>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_shipment_save_after>
        </events>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <sellercenter_vendor><to_order>*</to_order></sellercenter_vendor>
                <vendor_order_id><to_order>*</to_order></vendor_order_id>
            </sales_convert_quote>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <lime_sellercenter_sync_order_queue>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>lime_sellercenter/observer::processQueue</model>
                </run>
            </lime_sellercenter_sync_order_queue>
            <lime_sellercenter_autosync_order_process>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 * * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>lime_sellercenter/observer::autoDownload</model></run>
            </lime_sellercenter_autosync_order_process>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <lime_sellercenter>
                    <file>lime_sellercenter.xml</file>
                </lime_sellercenter>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <lime_sellercenter>
                                            <title>Sellercenter Settings</title>
                                        </lime_sellercenter>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <events>
          <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
              <observers>
                  <lime_sellercenter_listing_product>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>lime_sellercenter/adminhtml_observer</class>
                      <method>addProductListingBlock</method>
                  </lime_sellercenter_listing_product>
              </observers>
          </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
          <catalog_product_save_after>
              <observers>
                  <lime_sellercenter_listing_product>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>lime_sellercenter/adminhtml_observer</class>
                      <method>saveProductListingData</method>
                  </lime_sellercenter_listing_product>
              </observers>
          </catalog_product_save_after>
      </events>
      <global_search>
          <listing>
              <class>lime_sellercenter/adminhtml_search_listing</class>
              <acl>lime_sellercenter</acl>
          </listing>
      </global_search>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <lime_sellercenter translate="title" module="lime_sellercenter">
                                        <title>Sellercenter</title>
                                    </lime_sellercenter>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <lime_sellercenter translate="title" module="lime_sellercenter">
                        <title>Sell on Lazada</title>
                        <children>
                            <listing translate="title" module="lime_sellercenter">
                                <title>Listing</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </listing>
                        </children>
                    </lime_sellercenter>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <menu>
        <lime_sellercenter translate="title" module="lime_sellercenter">
            <title>Sell on Lazada</title>
            <sort_order>35</sort_order>
            <children>
                <listings translate="title" module="lime_sellercenter">
                    <title>Listings</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/sellercenter_listing</action>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                </listings>
            </children>
        </lime_sellercenter>
    </menu>
</config>
```

system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <lime translate="label">
            <label>LIME</label>
            <sort_order>500</sort_order>
        </lime>
    </tabs>

    <sections>
        <lime_sellercenter translate="label" module="lime_sellercenter">
            <label>Seller Center Integration</label>
            <tab>lime</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <lazada translate="label">
                    <label>Lazada Settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <status translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        </status>
                        <service_url translate="label">
                            <label>API URL: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends>
                                <status>1</status>
                            </depends>
                        </service_url>
                        <api_user translate="label">
                            <label>API User ID: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends>
                                <status>1</status>
                            </depends>
                        </api_user>
                        <api_key translate="label">
                            <label>API Key: </label>
                            <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends>
                                <status>1</status>
                            </depends>
                        </api_key>
                        <debugmode translate="label">
                            <label>Debug Mode: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        </debugmode>
                        <sync_orders_from translate="label">
                            <label>Sync Orders After: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <frontend_model>lime_sellercenter/adminhtml_system_config_date</frontend_model>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends>
                                <status>1</status>
                            </depends>
                            <comment>Leave field empty to disable order syncing.</comment>
                        </sync_orders_from>
                        <auto_download_time translate="label">
                            <label>Auto Sync Order At: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends>
                                <status>1</status>
                            </depends>
                            <comment>Enter 0 - 23. Separated by comma (eg. 1,6,13,23)</comment>
                        </auto_download_time>
                    </fields>
                </lazada>
            </groups>
        </lime_sellercenter>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Logout and log back in. That should help.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri thansk  its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it's cache playing the role. Just `Log Out` and `Log In` again. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956794/installing-a-new-magento-extension-requires-logout-login-otherwise-you-get-404) why you need to do this.

Also, consider adding **ACL** role, if you haven't already added.

Learn how to add ACL [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/404-not-found-error-while-creating-custom-group-and-fields-in-system-configurati).

Comment: WTF! Finally logout and login works, Thanks man. +1